# Quasar 2 Vue 3 how to access app.config.globalProperties through "this" object in .vue files?

Tags: vuejs2, global-variables, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using Quasar 2 Vue 3. Currently I need to `import app from "../boot/firebaseConfig";` in every `.vue` files and access global variables using `app.config.globalProperties.<foo>` syntax. Is there anyway to shorten this to just using `this.<foo>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  data() {
    return {
      db: app.config.globalProperties.$db
    }
  },
  methods: {
    method1() { this.db ...}
  }
```